# Looking for a desktop app to sort my photos library by face

Tags: windows, gratis, photography

I am looking for a desktop application that can index my local photo library and understand faces on its own. As a 2nd step I want to copy these found photos per each person into a separate folder. I am not looking for apps where I need to tag people first.

I believe Picasa was able to do that many years ago, but it no longer exists. I tried several new ones without success. I tried Google photos by uploading but it does not work with my account/country, there are many bugs reported around that. I am sure there must be a desktop application.

Any help or hints are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Desktop? Which desktop ? I.E which operating system? And, must it be free (add the [tag:gratis] tag, or do you have a budget in mind. The more info you give us, the more that we can help you (and this has the potential to be a great question +1 and marked as fvo(u)rite).

Comment: Windows 10. Yes in my case it should be free

Comment: I have added the relvant tags. I see that you ar enew, so adivise you to add tags & as much info as posisble to questions. The more info we have, the more that we can help you. WIthout these tags, you might get answers for Linux or Mac, costing $299. Good luck with your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Digikam](https://www.digikam.org/news/2020-07-19-7.0.0_release_announcement/) has facial detection. Adobe Lightroom also face detection. Some alternatives to Lightroom may also have face detect built in, without a subscription fee.

Comment: Digikam is useless when it comes to face detection unfortunately. It does match 5 different people as the same just because they all wear sunglasses. I am very surprised that this is such an issue in 2020. The Picasa app from 2005 or so could do that unasked within 1h and like 99.9% accuracy. I guess it just shows how far ahead this program was. I believe due to privacy concerns all such efforts are kinda blocked today....